# Raspberry Shut down After trying to connect fan

Tags: gpio, sd-card, power, pi-3b+

I just bought a new Raspberry Pi 3B+ UK and was working with it for about 2 hours, and then when I was not at home, my son noticed that the CPU is hot and tried to cool it down with a normal 5V PC fan by connecting the wires to the GPIO, and suddenly the raspberry shuts down (I think he had connected the wires wrong).

I want to turn it on but only the PWR light turns on and doesn't flash.

I have tested the SD card on other Raspberry Pi Imand it works.

Any ideas? Can I repair it?

Comment: Possibly you have fried the Raspberry Pi and to repair it, it's hard. You need to replace it.

Comment: Leave it alone for a day to see if the polyfuse blew then reset itself.  If it still doesn't work it needs replacing.